# How to make a language toggle in Yesod?

Tags: haskell, deployment, yesod

I want to add a button to my page that says "EN/PL" and when pressed it reloads the page with the other language (one button that performs PL -> EN or EN -> PL depending on current language selection). The problem is that I cannot find any way to query the current language settings so I cannot tell the program which language to switch to. I tried looking on hackage, hoogle and in the Yesod book and I could only find setLanguage, there doesn't seem to be a corresponding getLanguage function.

Is it possible to query the current language setting in Yesod or is there another way to implement a button like this?

Comment: One solution (or, hack) I've used for this is to just not use any built-in language handling, but rather a language parameter as part of the path type (`example.com/en` vs `example.com/pl`). Then you can simply switch languages by hopping between URLs, like any other movement on a webpage.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue.

in pl.msg:

```
OtherLang: en
```

in en.msg:

```
OtherLang: pl
```

And route that sets the language [like in the book](https://www.yesodweb.com/book/internationalization).

```
mkYesod "App" [parseRoute|
    /lang/#Text LangR GET

    ...
|]

getLangR :: Text -> Handler ()
getLangR lang = do
    setLanguage lang
    redirect HomeR
```

Then language preferences can be queries with

```
do
langs <- languages 
lang <- renderMessage "App" langs OtherLang

...

<a href=@{LangR lang}>
```